# Wordpress installation inside Vagrant box keeps redirecting back to http://localhost

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant

I am having a strange issue at the moment where when I browse to a port-forwarded URI (in this case http://localhost:9001) of a Vagrant box in my browser I get redirected back to localhost (default server). I'm not sure why this is happening and it's really frustrating.

On my guest machine I have the root folder hosted in /var/www/wordpress and this is my /nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            #proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }
```

}

Here is my Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# Set Vagrant box to use
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

# Configure port forwarding
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 9001, auto_correct: true

# Set synched folder
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/wordpress", create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data"

# Configure the VM
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "Pet Vets Vagrant Box"
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
end

# Set up shell provisioning
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
```

end

And my bootstrap.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Provisioning virtual machine..."
apt-get update

echo "Installing Tree..."
apt-get install tree

echo "Installing Git"
apt-get install git -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing Nginx"
apt-get install nginx -y >/dev/null

echo "Configuring Nginx"
cp /var/www/wordpress/nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost > /dev/null

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_vhost

rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

service nginx restart > /dev/null

echo "Updating PHP repository"
apt-get install python-software-properties build-essential -y > /dev/null
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 -y > /dev/null
apt-get update > /dev/null

echo "Installing PHP"
apt-get install php5-common php5-dev php5-cli php5-fpm libssh2-php -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing PHP extensions"
apt-get install curl php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql -y > /dev/null
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

The Wordpress installation works fine when I host it on nGinx locally (not using Vagrant) but as soon as I place it in a Vagrant box it doesn't want to play. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't with nGinx it was with the Wordpress config.

I had siteurl and home in the wp_options table both set to http::localhost where it needed to be set to http://localhost:9001.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Thanks